# GridView HyperLinkField onclick handler ASPX VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have this code in Gridview:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="data" 
                     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SMSReport.aspx?data={0}&amp;db=1"
                     HeaderText="Ataskaita"
                     Text="Ataskaita" />
```

and I need to add on-click handler(like message do you want to continue?). I tried to google, but what i found is that you can't add handler  in 'HyperLinkField'. Any ideas how to add on-click effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lose the hyperlink it put in a button. It would solve the onclick handler problem and give you some more flexibility.

- Here is the MSDN article to add yes/no [message boxes](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETMessageBox-3e8c6273)
- Here is another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720143/asp-net-web-application-message-box) article walking you through it (it's at the bottom)
- Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/619834/how-to-add-button-field-in-gridview-for-each-row-i) on how to add a button to the gridview