# JavaScript confirm in ASP.NET 4.0 VB.Net

Tags: javascript, confirm

I have tried multiple things I have found on the web.  What I am looking for is just to confirm the user is hitting cancel to NOT save changes.  I need the code on the server side to get the result from the confirm.

I have a master page and 1 content page.  I am new to using clientside so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I tried but it only worked when I started the app.
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: Is this WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This works great! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720143/asp-net-web-application-message-box

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cancelButtonClicked(event) {
  if (confirm("Confirm you don't want to save changes?")) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="cancelButtonClicked(event)">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: How do I get the response server-side?  I also need to use server-side controls.  This is a ASP.Net application.

Comment: This is what I tried but it kept firing at page_load.  I put the JS code on my master page and content page and still had the same issue.https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx.