# Windows.Forms object not showing up in publish/deployment, but shows up in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, deployment, dialog

I'm having an issue with a build that involves the use of a `DialogResult` object not showing up when I

1. Publish the app *or*
2. Commit the changes and deploy to production.

The quirky part is it will work and pop-up with a local build (Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or just <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Is there an issue with windows forms objects not working in this instance or is something else possibly the issue? Both the deployment and publish direct to the site that has a special small addition to the code that allows a photo to be displayed that had been previously blocked by CORS policy. I'm not sure what else to add as I can't think of anything relevant that would potentially affect this.

As requested, the snippet of code that is not showing up.

```
 DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this photo?", "Delete Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
 if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
   //Delete File and all related material.
 }
 else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
 {
      PicturePlaceholder.Controls.Clear();
 }

 //Reload photos.
```

Comment: Paste snippet of code where DialogResult behaves differently

Comment: I have posted the code above.

Comment: How deployed program is executed, user installs it and runs it with local computer?

Comment: It is committed to a repository where it is then deployed from Jenkins to an inhouse website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between debug/relese modes and [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) class behaviour.

If I understood right, you are trying to show Messagebox from web application running on web server. Short answer is: **Don't**.

Longer answer with some alternatives is given i.e [here](https://forums.asp.net/p/907491/1019440.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720143/asp-net-web-application-message-box).

MessageBox and whole [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/)-framework is meant for Windows Desktop GUI applications. In your case problem is context where program is running. When executing windows forms UI-application in server context, process should be executed in [UserInteractive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.userinteractive(v=vs.110).aspx) mode, and there should be proper user logged in with active desktop session running on default desktop.