# How to create a message box in Visual Basic Net 2003?

Tags: vb.net, webforms, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to create a web form using Visual Basic Net 2003 which I plan on adding a message box alerting user if they are missing data input.

If I'm not mistaken normally for the newer Visual Basic Net 2010 the code to create message box would be

```
messagebox.show("Insert msg here.")
```

There is no need to declare anything, yes? At least that is the case for VBA.

Because that is what I'm getting when I'm using 2003. It says that

```
messagebox is not declared
```

even though it is not supposed to be a variable. What is supposed to be the correct method to create message box in VB Net 2003?

Comment: You are mistaken. `MessageBox.Show` is code that is used in Windows Forms and WPF, where there is a `MessageBox` class. It's not dependent on the VB version (other than WPF didn't exist until VB 2008). There's still no `MessageBox` class in Web Forms in VB 2017 or the unreleased VB 2019. You generally use a JavaScript library of some sort to display dialogues in ASP.NET applications.

Comment: I don't believe the MessageBox is available in webforms. MessageBox is for Windows.Forms applications. I think there is a javascript alert that can run on the client,

Comment: I see. Then I'll just have to work around that with a label then. Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720143/asp-net-web-application-message-box/9720205#) out.