# How can I show a MessageBox in my asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

How can I show a MessageBox in my ASP.NET page?  After completion I want bZ for it to display a message.

Comment: what do you mean by Message Box? Are you trying to show an alert or Confirmation box or Prompt Box?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show MessageBox on asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301770/how-to-show-messagebox-on-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

easy way to do is

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

or

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Hello world');</script>"; 
if (!page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
{
 page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", script, false);
}
```

Comment: Pranay Rana: Thanks i m trying ur code but  problem is that  when i click button it display message  but not showed background content

Comment: @PrashantIsapure - because its postback the page thats y...if you dont want to post back pag than put page in update panel and make use of scriptmanager for registring script

Answer (score 0):

try using:
On Code behind File

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('hello World');", true);
    }
```

On aspx file:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with all the web-forms encrypted answers? Just because he happens to be using webforms doesn't mean a webforms solution is a good one.

use either

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('hello world');</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript"> confirm('are you there?');</script>
```

for a message box or confirmation box

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://needim.github.com/noty/) jquery plug-in

and in code behind :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Key", "noty({ text: '<div>Thanks<br/><br/>Saved!</div>', layout: 'center', type: 'information' });", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project i show message box for confirmation when use click on delete button clink and show a div like this it's below

In my view i have a div which i show for message

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete Country">
    <p>
        Are you soure you wont to delete this record ?</p>
</div>
```

and my delete link button is

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkShow" runate="server" class="lnkDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and i use this link like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".lnkDelete").button();       
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            model: true,
            width: 300,
            resizable: false,
            height: 200
        });

        $(".lnkDelete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targeturl = $(this).attr("href");


            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        window.location.href = targeturl;
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
        }
```

i think this will help you